# How to play a video in a Laravel 5.1 application

Tags: html, video, mime-types, laravel-blade

I'm a beginner to Laravel 5, and I'm trying to play a video in my page.

Video code :

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <video controls="" autoplay="" width="640" height="360">
        <source src="{{ $lesson->download }}{{$video}}" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
    <!-- <iframe
        width="100%"
        height="315"
        src="{{ $lesson->download }}{{$video}}"
        frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe> -->
    <hr/>
</div>
```

The result :
[image: Result of the play]

When I inspect, the url is correct :
[image: Inspect]

By the way, when I use the `iframe` for Youtube videos, it works.

Thank you

Comment: your video path seems strange to me : `c:\wamp64\.../public/uploads/test.mp4`.

Comment: @zack-p are you sure that such type of path works generally?

Comment: hello, yes the path is correct

Answer (score 0):

it's my code. maybe works for you:

```html
@if(strpos($vidUrl,"video:")!== false) 
   <video onclick="showVideo()"style="display: block;"
           src="{{str_replace('video:','', $vidUrl)}}" controls width="500"
@endif
```

my $vidUrl is something like "video://SOME_URL//"

Comment: hello, the code didn't work , is it correct ? how to use $vidUrl  with my case ? {{ $lesson->download }}{{$video}}

Comment: what are download and vidoe variables? did you use array or std class?